# PowerShell comment URL link possible?

Tags: powershell, ide

I'm not sure which IDE I was using at the time (Android Studio or Visual Studio), but I was able to embed a clickable URL link in a comment block.

Is it possible to do this in the PowerShell ISE?

Thanks.

Comment: Comments are just chunks of text. Whether or not an IDE wants to overlay a text-URI with a clickable link is up to the IDE. ISE doesn't do that.

Comment: I realise that, I was just wondering if there was a way to wrap a URL text in special characters to have the IDE interpret it as a link. Oh well.

Comment: Visual Studio does do this.